# Change Dockerfile for GCP Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-composer

I'm using GCP Composer 2 for a Production environment.
I want to change the DockerFile that GCP Composer is using for building image for itself by adding an OS package (like apt-get libmcrypt-dev) for the new image.

Could anyone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Firstly, you would need to [create](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/os-packages/debian/apt-quickstart) a Debian package into a repository, so with this you will be able to run the apt run commands into your image.

After you are done with the step above, you can use [this](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/quickstart#create_an_environment) public documentation that Google provides, where you can create your own environment on Composer 2 running this command:

```
gcloud composer environments create ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
    --location LOCATION \
    --image-version IMAGE_VERSION
```

Just have in mind that Composer 2 is still in development, and many of the tools that Composer offers are still in development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there a way to add ->` RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    php5-mcrypt \
    python-pip`
to docker image that Composer generated for itself in artifact registry?

Comment: @vamper1234 I updated my answer, hope it helps you.